# executionPriorityOrder vanishes from UI after deploying pipeline

Tags: azure-data-factory

Here is some weird behavior of ADF Author/Deploy UI that I came across. You will see the same if you try.

Open any existing pipeline in ADF, in any of its activity (e.g. my activity type is HDInsightHive) within policy block there is an option called:-

**"executionPriorityOrder": "NewestFirst",**

if you hover over it, you see another valid value for this is **OldestFirst**, so if you change this to:-

**"executionPriorityOrder": "OldestFirst",**

Click on Deploy. After deploying & provisioning, again open that pipeline and you will notice that now the entire executionPriorityOrder statement missing. Is it because OldestFirst is default or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct, "OldestFirst" is the default value for executionPriorityOrder. In this property's case, the default value is not displayed. I agree this can be confusing, however the value is in fact being preserved in the defintion for your pipeline.

P.S. Sorry for the very late response. The ADF team is making a push to respond more quickly to community forum questions.